# Applying function across column for each row to create new variable in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, loops

I have a 'dataframe' of an experiment that estimate participants' rate of discount by asking e.g. choice3: would they prefer to take $100 now or $105 in 1 month;  choice 4: would they prefer to take $100 now or $120 in 1 month.

Below is an example for index being the participant id and choice1 to choice4 as the increasing amount of compensation proposed for delaying the reward for 1 month:

| Index | choice1 | choice2 | choice3 | choice4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 | 102 | 105 | 120 |
| 2 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 120 |
| 3 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 4 | 100 | 100 | 105 | 120 |

and I am trying to create a new column 'discount' that take the *percentage change* of the first time the participant deviates from choosing $100 e.g. 0.02 for participant 1 and 0.2 for participant 2, etc.

I have attempted to apply a function to create a new variable as a column:

```
def dis_cal(row):
    dis = 0
    col_index = 0
    rate = (lambda now, later: (later - now)//now)
    while dis == 0 and col_index < 3:
        dis = rate(float(row[col_index]), float(row[col_index + 1]))
        col_index += 1 

def discount(df):
    df.loc[:,"discount"] = df.apply(lambda row: dis_cal(row), axis = 1)
```

But *dis* in the while loop is all equals to 0.0 which shows as **None** in the new column *discount*

This is my first data analysis project and I would really need some help. Thanks alot!

Comment: What does `participant` and `month` mean in your question? Your dataframe doesn't contain these information.

Comment: You write `col_index += col_index + 1` which should be either `col_index = col_index + 1` or `col_index += 1`. And you should consider the situation `col_index` is out of the max length of df columns.

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh for your comment, I have updated my question and changed to `col_index += 1`. But even though the code could run, the new column _discount_ is with value **None** and there is a warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For participant 0, The while loop wont terminate. So you must add a constraint on the col_index.

```
while dis == 0 and col_index<3
```

This should work.
And one more thing, we will have to return "rate" from the function.

```
col_index += col_index + 1
```

This should be replaced with

```
col_index = col_index + 1
```

Comment: Thanks @rupinderg00 for your reply. I have updated the code based on your advice but now even though the it could run, the new column _discount_ is with **None** value and with a warning message "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Comment: Try Updating the line:
df.loc[ : ,"discount"] = df.apply(lambda row: dis_cal(row), axis = 1)

Comment: Thanks! @rupingderg00 The error message is gone now after using df.loc[:, " dicscount"] and I have updated the code on my post. However, the new column is still having **None** as value. So I have try to print out _ids_ in the while loop and found they are all **0.0**. So I am now suspecting if row[col_index] would actually literate over the column?

Comment: @VLWH I asked you to return variable `dis` from the function. Please do that. I think that will work fine. Mark the solution as accepted if it works or revert back in case of any doubt